# Add field to document using cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I wanted to make the id of each document as a field of that document so that I can store it inside the doc. here is the cloud function I created:

```
 exports.assignPID = functions.database
.ref('/players/{playerId}')
.onCreate((snapshot,context)=>{
    const playerId = context.params.playerId;
    console.log("new player "+playerId);

    // const data = snapshot.val();
    return snapshot.ref.update({'pid': playerId})
})
```

this deploys without any errors but whenever I add a new document to the 'players' collection there is no change in the document whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you use the word "document" to describe your data, which is a Firestore concept, and you've tagged this question google-cloud-firestore.  However, the code you've written is for Realtime Database, which is a completely different product.  So it will never run in response to changes in Firestore.

When you declare a function with `functions.database`, that's means Realtime Database.  Instead, you should declare a [Firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) with `functions.firestore`.  Please read the linked documentation for information about how to do that.